# Run content script loop only when tab is active

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am working on a chrome extension that uses content scripts to runs a loop. The tasks ran in the loop can consume quite some memory, and when having a lot of open tabs it impacts on the browser performance.

I am looking to run the loop only when the tab is active.

I am using `onMessage.addListener` my background page, then I can `sendMessage` from the content script and check the `sender.tab.id` against `chrome.tabs.getSelected`. But since sendMessage is asynchronous, I am forced to use `setInterval` for the "is tab active" check to update the variable that allows the loop to run or not.

Is there a better way to find if a tab is active from content scripts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API), I think check

```
if (document.visibilityState === "hidden")
```

can solve your problem.

And I'm not sure what you did in the loop, if just to detect tab state, you can also use visibilitychange event listener instead.

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function () {
  if (document.hidden) {
    //...
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: It's a shame that Google thinks that all of the chrome.tabs object methods are off-limits to content scripts in Chrome extensions and hamstrings us. I was so delighted to see this answer as a workaround. It works well.